# What are functional and non functional parts of an application?

Tags: requirements

I was asked this question in an interview.

What are functional and non functional parts of an application ?

Comment: Non-functional are not actually *parts* but more like *aspects* or *characteristics*.

Comment: You could argue that the non-functional parts of the application are the bits that are broken — the ones that don't work.  However, non-functional requirements are slightly different.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_requirement) parts are those that relate to the function of the application - what it does.

[Non functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) are the parts that do not directly relate to the function - things like:

- performance
- quality
- portability
- maintainability
- quality
- availability
- extensibility
- and many more...

For example, in a calculator application, the functional parts are how the input and output work and the calculation logic/operation itself.

Non functional would be the usability, quality, performance and other aspects that do not have direct bearing on the calculator operations.

Comment: I would add maintainability, availability and extensibility to this.

Answer (score 3):

*Functional* relates to the features of the application. i.e. **what** it **does**. The *non-functional* parts are characteristics like:

- performance
- compatibility with previous versions
- security
- usability
- how well it performs under load
- how it handles failover scenarios

Comment: I'd put *what* in boldface, too.